# Last Button in UIScrollView add target doesn't effect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift3, uibutton

I have a list of category add I created buttons for each category in a scroll view
and a last button is ALL button for all products. But some how it didn't have any action I added. 
this is my code
First I make a function to create buttons to add to view

```
func catButtonView(buttonSize:CGSize) -> UIView {
    let buttonView = UIView()
    buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
    buttonView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
    let padding = CGSize(width:0, height:0)
    buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(categories.count)
    buttonView.frame.size.height = (buttonSize.height +  2.0 * padding.height )
    //add buttons to the view
    var buttonPosition = CGPoint(x:padding.width * 0.5, y:padding.height)
    let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
    let hueIncrement = 1.0 / CGFloat(categories.count)
    var newHue = hueIncrement
    for i in 0...(categories.count)  {

        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom) as UIButton
        button.frame.size = buttonSize
        button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
        button.setBackgroundImage(R.image.button(), for: .normal)
        button.setBackgroundImage(R.image.button_selected(), for: .selected)

        if(i==categories.count) {
            button.setTitle("ALL", for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setTitle(categories[i].name, for: .normal)
        }
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
        newHue = newHue + hueIncrement
        button.tag = i+1
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(catButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonView.addSubview(button)


    }
    return buttonView
}
```

this is action func

```
func catButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    print(sender.tag)
    if(self.selectedCat != sender.tag-1) {
        let lastBtn = catScrollView.viewWithTag(selectedCat+1) as? UIButton
        lastBtn?.setBackgroundImage(R.image.button(), for: .normal)
        self.selectedCat = sender.tag-1
        self.itemsCollection.reloadData()
        sender.setBackgroundImage(R.image.button_selected(), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

then add to scroll view

```
let catScrollingView = catButtonView(buttonSize: CGSize(width: 200.0, height:50.0))
    catScrollView.contentSize = catScrollingView.frame.size
    catScrollView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    catScrollView.addSubview(catScrollingView)
    catScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    catScrollView.indicatorStyle = .default

    self.itemsCollection.reloadData()
```

Anyone know what I missed?

Comment: check your scroll view hight and your button position and change one line that  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(catButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchDown) and check output

Comment: Thanks, I think I know the problem, the frame width only for categories.count, but not categories.count +1 where "ALL" button are

Comment: ya thats i want to tell you that your buttons are not in view so add it in view

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `if statement` in your `catButtonPressed` function is false with the last button's tag, which makes the code inside never be executed.

Let's say you have **5** categories so your `categories.count = 5`. So your `self.selectedCat` ranges **from 0 to 4**. In your `for i in 0...(categories.count)` the last button's tag is `button.tag = 5`

Now in your `catButtonPressed` function. If the last button is the last category, then your `self.selectedCat` will be **4** and `sender.tag` will be **5**

```
func catButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){
    print(sender.tag)
    if(4 != 5-1) { 
         // Any code in here will never be executed because 4 != 4 is false
    }
}
```